# Plot conditional chart in Google Sheets and automate the plotting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-sheets-formula

I have data in Google Sheets as shown in attached **first photo**. I would like to plot Date v/s Vol in a chart. However, I would also like to indicate red 'X' (or 'O' or anything) to the datapoints where Condition1, Condition2, Condition3 are all = Yes (see **second photo**). These are the rows indicated in yellow color.

1. How to accomplish such chart plotting (**second photo**) in Google Sheet chart?
2. Is there any way to build a formula which takes data location (in this case B2:F38) as input and automatically plots such chart starting at, say, cell H6?

**Link to file**: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/102uEOgYxt4JfJQuYfroBZnaX3CCbmavD3eSh--qDJh4/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about using the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

When your sample Spreadsheet is used, please put this formula to the cell "G3".

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((D3:D="Yes")*(E3:E="Yes")*(F3:F="Yes")=1,C3:C,""))
```

- In this formula, the columns "D", "E", and "F" are `yes`, and the value of column "C" is returned.

#### Testing:

When this formula is used, the values are retrieved as follows. And, create a chart using the columns "B", "C" and "G". And, when the circle of the values of column "G" is large, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When you use `X` mark as the plot of column "G", you can obtain the chart with `X`.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike , your solution works. However, please shed light on-- (1)  how do I get 'X' on the plot? What chart properties do I need to change for this?   (2) Once column G is created, is there any formula to automatically generate the chart (data B2:B38 and G2:G38 will be input to such formula)?

Comment: @Sinha Thank you for replying. About `(1) how do I ger 'X' on the plot?`, by selecting the column "G", [Customize]->[Series]->[Point shape]->"X mark". About `(2) Once column G is created, is there any formula to automatically generate the chart (data B2:B38 and G2:G38 will be input to such formula)?`, when the built-in function is used, I think that the chart cannot be directly created and modified by the built-in formula. If you want to create a chart including such column "G", I think that the script is required to be used.

Comment: @Sinha Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.